# Must the matrix in the product be right-stochastic?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-matrices

Let $A$ be a square right-stochastic matrix, so that $A$ has nonnegative entries and each row sums to unity.

For an invertible square matrix $B$, the product $A B$ is also right-stochastic. Must it be that $B$ itself is right-stochastic? I don't know, but the converse certainly holds since the product of right-stochastic matrices is right-stochastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. As an example, take
$$
A = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1 & 1/2\\ 0&1/2}.
$$
$B$ is not right-stochastic, but $AB = A$ is right-stochastic.

Comment: Thank you; this is a very helpful answer. I forgot to write that $B$ is invertible. (The question is now updated.) Do you still believe there's a counter example?

Comment: The answer is still no, see my edit

Comment: Much appreciated!